# What DNS server is the first in being queried when trying to found an IP?

Tags: domain-name-system

I learning networking, specially how DNS protocol works.

I've watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eA9mnY1Z2so, the video's duration is of 1 hour, the explanation about DNS starts in the minute 18:35.

I understand the following:

Each portion (the text before each dot) in a full dns domain name makes reference to a server that controls a set of ip directions, for example .com makes reference to a servers that have ip directions of the web servers of commercial websites. for example the machine with .com name has this ip's:

```
buy.com               ----- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
anothercommercial.com ----- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

**.com** is a top level domain name and the server which have the ip of the machine with **.com** is a root server which controls the top levels domains and have their ip directions.

what server is the first in being queried to find the ip of **buy.com**?

I've heard that ISP gives an Ip of a domain server, but I don't know if that server then help us giving us the root database zone Ip which then give us the **.com** ip and finally in **.com** we find the ip of buy.com

Help me to understand this please.

Comment: If you use a video as a reference and it's an hour long, you can't expect someone to actually watch it, but should reference the exact time on the video and even better, cite it. I took a look at the video by jumping through it. Frankly, it's not a good lecture on the subject: it seems to contain a lot of unrelated, confusing details and it's not accurate, either. For example in 35:01  Prof.I.Sengupta demonstrates how he doesn't understand the DNS architecture at all!

Comment: Thanks, your answer help me...I think more slowly the way the professor explain the steps for search the Ip for a domain has no much sense...I've added the minute the professor starts explaining in the question description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question on what is the first server that gets queried depends on:

- Circumstances: what's already cached and where?
- The part of the DNS we are focusing on:

  - How a *recursive* name server starts hierachically from the root?
  - How a clients sends a query to its nearest recursive name server?
- Abstraction level: are we interested just in the delegation hierachy or actual records.

This answer aims at explaining the flow with different levels of abstration, discuss what's left out to simplify it a bit... and correct the misunderstanding left by the presentation you had seen. Let's start with this (Jean Piaget's) *accommodation*...

---

### To correct the misleading

**Prof.I.Sengupta explains the recursive name resolution inaccurately and misleadingly**. Starting from [35:01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eA9mnY1Z2so#t=35m1s) there's a slide showing this figure. The warning around it is mine. ;-)

> [image: Incorrect undestarting of DNS]

The hierarchy in the *authoritative* DNS is one way: recursion starts always downwards from the root, and never up towards the root like in this picture. Furthermore, this suggests that all the DNS queries and their responses between TLD's would be going through the root name servers. Clearly that can't be the case, and the root name servers are loaded enough even with their current responsibilities i.e. simply with serving the delegation of control down to the TLD name servers.

Although some name servers could have both recursive and authoritative roles, that's not recommended, and *open recursive name service* is even prohibited in the [IANA Ttechnical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements). There are several reasons for this isolation:

- Preventing *amplification attacks* ([RFC 5358, 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5358#section-4)).
- Preventing *DNS cache poisoning*, although this is mostly a historical reason best explained in the 3rd edition of *Nemeth, E., Snyder, G., Seebass, S., & Hein, T. (2000). UNIX system administration handbook. Pearson Education.* (Chapter 16 THE DOMAIN NAME SYSTEM; The BIND software; Authoritative and caching-only servers.):

  > In BIND4 and BIND 8, it wasn't a good idea to use a single name serevr
  > as an authoritative server for some zones and as a caching server for
  > others. Each named ran with a single in-memory database, and
  > cross-contamination could occur if memory was tight and cached data
  > mixed with authoritative data. BIND 9 has eliminated this problem, so
  > mix away.
- For *stability / load balancing*: authorative name servers are crucial part of the Internet, as almost everything else relies on DNS. Therefore, we shouldn't allow technical errors or high loads an a recursive server to affect the performance of this system.

---

### Different levels of abstraction

Many pictures on the subject are simplified to **not take caching into consideration**.

- Marshall Brain: [How Domain Name Servers Work](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/dns.htm) (already mentioned in Tim's answer)
- Lorraine Bellon: [What is the difference between authoritative and recursive DNS nameservers?](https://umbrella.cisco.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-authoritative-and-recursive-dns-nameservers)
- SophieDogg: [An Intro to DNS](https://sophiedogg.com/intro-to-dns/). The following version of this illustration & the citation are from there:

  > Below is an example of a recursive DNS query. It is important to know
  > that a recursive server always has a copy of the IP addresses of the
  > root nameservers, in order to provide the necessary addresses for step
  > #2 in the figure below. This list of root nameservers need to be kept up to date, or else the recursive nameserver will not know where to
  > start its lookups!
  >
  > [image: SophieDogg: Example of a Recursive DNS Transaction]

If we add caching on different levels (browser, OS, recursive server), the picture gets a little more complicated. This illustration from The [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/): [DNS Name Resolution Process](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSNameResolutionProcess-2.htm) shows what happens if **nothing was cached**.

> [image: Figure 245: Example Of The DNS Name Resolution Process]
>
> **Figure 245: Example Of The DNS Name Resolution Process**
>
> This fairly complex example illustrates a typical DNS name resolution
> using both iterative and recursive resolution. The user types in a DNS
> name (“www.net.compsci.googleplex.edu”) into a Web browser, which
> causes a DNS resolution request to be made from her client machine’s
> resolver to a local DNS name server. That name server agrees to
> resolve the name recursively on behalf of the resolver, but uses
> iterative requests to accomplish it. These requests are sent to a DNS
> root name server, followed in turn by the name servers for “.edu”,
> “googleplex.edu” and ‘compsci.googleplex.edu”. The IP address is then
> passed to the local name server and then back to the user’s resolver
> and finally, her Web browser software.

Here we already have almost everything, if we only add that:

- **Caching**:

  - The client could already know the IP address, and 3-15 can be omitted.
  - Everything could be already cached on the recursive server, and 5-13 can be omitted.
  - Assuming `www.net.compsci.googleplex.edu` was recently queried, the recursive name server already knows `compsci.googleplex.edu` name servers; when querying e.g. for `sw.compsci.googleplex.edu`, 5-10 can be omitted.
  - Even more often the recursive name server already know TLD name servers; omit 5-6.
- Name servers are returned as `NS` records, but for every level you need the actual IP addresses. If they are not returned with the `NS` records, the corresponding `A` records needs to be queried too. This might happen e.g. if the **name servers located on a different TLD**. In this case, a recursive name server may need to start from the root twice. Closely related to this, ***glue records*** are whole another subject.
- Not all local DNS servers used perform the recursion by themselves, but they may ask from other recursive name server called ***forwarders***. Likewise, the forwarders have caching capabilities, and their relation is similar to the situation between the OS level cache and the local name server on this picture.

If we try and add all this into a same illustration, it would be as complex as any explanation.